# Can I use CSS3DRenderer with VREffect?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make a VR app, and it has been going quite smoothly with the help of StereoEffect and VRControls. My app, however, has a few elements in CSS3D, and I am using CSS3DStereoRenderer and StereoEffect along with VRControls to achieve VR. This works very well on the Mac, where I can mirror my screen on the Rift.

On Windows, however, Rift has no support for extended desktop anymore, hence I have to use WebVR to send the display directly to the Rift. I can use VREffect to do this, however, this only works with WebGLRenderer and not CSS3DRenderer. How do I use VREffect with CSS3DObjects?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with the WebVR APIs. The VR context requires a WebGL Canvas, not DOM elements, and CSS3DRenderer can't do that. You might be able to get it to work in non-VR devices (e.g. by tricking the WebVR polyfill) but for VR devices you'll need to use WebGL.